# Kinship between objects, generating error in the rotation of the child mesh

Tags: python, mesh

[image: error bbox in letters]

[image: plate rotation]

[image: letter rotation]

[image: kinship between the sign and the letters]

I have a code in Blender that generates images of plates with different strings. But I'm having a problem, the rotations only appear for the plate and not for the letters, which means that the bbox doesn't follow the letters properly. How to make the rotation of each letter appear without changing the geometry of the letters and their positions

Comment: pls provide blend file so we know what you did, because you didn't show us. thx.

Comment: Hello, Victor.. from what I can see here, the numbers appear to be meshes correctly parented to the plate? Is your complaint that the green (interface??) does not follow the transform? Did you write the script? If not, where does it come from, and what does it promise?

Comment: I think you got local transform, that is relative to parent. To get world-space location you should use `object.matrix_world.translation` You have not provided a code sample, so I can't aid more

Comment: The objective would be to use another Python code to mark the letters with bbox, however the rotations of the letters appear to be zero because they are child objects of the PLACA mesh. In my code I have a function that "Calculates a 2D bounding box of a 3D object relative to a camera and scene." and another that "Gets the bounding box of an object even after rotations and movements." then save the notes in COCO

Comment: If the letters are children to PLACA try the following procedure. Clear the rotation of PLACA  - Select all children and Clear Parent > Clear and Keep Transformation. Re-parent the letters to PLACA again. Rotate PLACA back to X 90 degrees.